# VaadIN combox BeanContainer

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm using an beanContainer to fill an combobox en to show the "loginName" as the selection field.

DTO

```
public class UserDTO extends Observable implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int userId;
private String loginName;
private String password;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private AddressDTO address;
private boolean privacyAddress;
private String pictureLocation;
private Date birthDate;
private RightDTO right;
private String email;
private String telephone;
private boolean privacyTelephone;
private String mobile;
private boolean privacyMobile;
private int minLimit;
private int maxLimit;
private int balance;
private boolean active;
...

//filling the combobox with UserDTO's by BeanContainer
    BeanContainer<String, UserDTO> beanContainer = new BeanContainer<String, UserDTO>(
            UserDTO.class);
    beanContainer.setBeanIdProperty("loginName");
    cmbSolver.setImmediate(true);
    cmbSolver.setNewItemsAllowed(false);
    cmbSolver.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
    cmbSolver.setContainerDataSource(beanContainer);
    cmbSolver.setItemCaptionMode(ItemCaptionMode.ID);
    cmbSolver.setItemCaptionPropertyId("loginName");
    ArrayList<UserDTO> solvers = pc.retrieveSolvers();
    for (int i = 0; i < solvers.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("solver = " + solvers.get(i));
    }
    beanContainer.addAll(solvers);
```

When I select the value of the combobox I thought I would get UserDTO but I get the String of the loginName.  Is there a way to retrieve the selected UserDTO directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    final BeanItemContainer<SimpleBean> container = new BeanItemContainer<>(SimpleBean.class);//create a container for beans
    container.addBean(new SimpleBean("Some string"));//add bean to the container
    container.addBean(new SimpleBean("Some string 123"));
    final ComboBox combo = new ComboBox("choose", container);/*create a combo box with caption "choose". the second argument is the datasource - this is the place from where the combo box will get its values.*/
    combo.setItemCaptionMode(ItemCaptionMode.ID);/*this will "tell" to combo box to use the container ids as values that must be showed in the combo box*/
    combo.setItemCaptionPropertyId("name");//"tell" to the combobox from which property of the container to get the values which must be displayed to the user
    combo.setImmediate(true);//this will generate browser request to the server immediate after user change the value of the combobox
    combo.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event)/*this method will be invoked when the combo box value was changed*/
        {

            System.out.println(combo.getValue());//this will return the selected object. 
        }
    });
```

public class SimpleBean
{
  private String name;

```
public SimpleBean(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}


public String getName()
{
    return name;
}


public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Comment: some explanation of what you are doing would really help. thanks

Comment: First of all, thank you for the reply.  I would like to create an combobox where I can select the UserDTO.  The name in the combobox that I would like to show is the LoginName of the UserDTO, but I would like to retrieve the selected UserDTO depending on what is selected in the Combobox.  When I use combobox.getValue() I get a String and not the UserDTO.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to get the UserDTO-object when you call cbmSolver.getValue().

Here is my suggestion:

```
BeanItemContainer<UserDTO> beanContainer = new BeanItemContainer<UserDTO>(UserDTO.class);
    beanContainer.setBeanIdProperty("loginName");
    cmbSolver.setImmediate(true);
    cmbSolver.setNewItemsAllowed(false);
    cmbSolver.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
    cmbSolver.setContainerDataSource(beanContainer);
    cmbSolver.setItemCaptionMode(ItemCaptionMode.ID);
    cmbSolver.setItemCaptionPropertyId("loginName");
    ArrayList<UserDTO> solvers = pc.retrieveSolvers();
    beanContainer.addAll(solvers);
```

This will list a ComboBox with objects of UserDTO with the caption from the field "loginName". When cbmSolver.getValue() is called, you will get the object and not the string of "longinName".

Comment: I get the following error : Incorrect number of arguments for type BeanContainer<IDTYPE,BEANTYPE>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <UserDTO> !?

Comment: I'm so sorry. My bad, it should be BeanItemContainer<UserDTO>, not BeanContainer<UserDTO>. Hope it works out!